# Root Android with no apps

Tags: root-access

I want to root my Android 11 on Samsung A72 without using any third part app. Is their a way?

I cannot find anything on google on duckduckgo that mentions a terminal or a manual root.

Comment: A rooted device needs at least an su binary and and typically an app that handles su requests, therefore rooting without e.g Magisk is not possible. But if you are referring to those only on ancient Android versions usable apps like Kingroot and so on, then it is possible. Just unlock the bootloader and [install Magisk](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html).

Comment: To piggy-back on @Robert's comment, [Magisk](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#samsung-system-as-root) is trusted and opensource, so there's no reason not to use it _(AFAIK, stay away from SuperSU as it's no longer opensource as of a few yrs ago)_